# Erro mysql: 1054. Unknown column 'movimentacao_almox.cod_promob' in 'where clause' mesmo eu não utilizando esta coluna nos parâmetros

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando fazer um insert no meu banco de dados com o seguinte comando:

```
UPDATE movimentacao_almox SET quantidade = 100, qtd_pendente = 2 WHERE id = 1113;
```

porém recebo este erro:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'movimentacao_almox.cod_promob' in 'where clause'
```

Como podem perceber, não utilizo esta coluna `movimentacao_almox.cod_promob` no meu comando. 
Gostaria de entender o que está acontecendo e como resolver.

Comment: Teria como fornecer mais contexto para o erro que você está tendo? Tem mais alguma query sendo executada nesse momento?

Comment: Bem lembrado.. tem uma trigger no Before Update:      UPDATE cadastro_mp SET estoque_atual = old.movimentacao_almox.quantidade + new.movimentacao_almox.quantidade 
WHERE 
cadastro_mp.cod_promob = movimentacao_almox.cod_promob AND cadastro_mp.almoxarifado = movimentacao_almox.almoxarifado;
END

Comment: Provavelmente está aí teu problema então, ele não tá encontrando esse `cod_promob` antes de atualizar o teu registro.

Comment: O estranho é que a coluna existe em todas as tabelas referenciadas....
Vou tentar alterar o Before por After update

Comment: Veja lá e nos confirme... ;)

Comment: Funcionou!! Vou postar as alterações que fiz como resposta! Obrigado

Comment: Excelente cara! Bora pra outra... ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Joel me lembrou que existia mais uma query sendo rodada junto com o código acima, que é uma trigger Befor Update:

```
UPDATE cadastro_mp SET estoque_atual = old.movimentacao_almox.quantidade + 
new.movimentacao_almox.quantidade WHERE cadastro_mp.cod_promob = 
movimentacao_almox.cod_promob AND cadastro_mp.almoxarifado = 
movimentacao_almox.almoxarifado;
```

eu não precisava especificar o nome da tabela novamente `old.movimentacao_almox.quantidade`, era apenas `old.quantidade`.
Fiz isso no restante do código e funcionou!